# A strange limit switch design?

Tags: switches, relay, automotive

I cannot understand how the limit switch design in this schematic works.  It appears to me to loop around on itself.  How does it work?

[image: Schematic]

Comment: Mmmmpf.  I expect that somebody got carried away while putting in the connection dots, and shouldn't have put in the two by the relays near pins 8 and 7.  In other words, the diagram is wrong.

Comment: @JRE Unless it's a Renault, then I completely believe the diagram.